# Is there an onDestroy hook available within Cordova plugins for Android?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I've been crawling around for this answer a while now including surfing Cordova's core source files and I'm beginning to believe that onDestroy() events  (as well as onCreate()) are not available within Cordova plugins for Android. Is this true, and if so, why?

It would be easy enough to fire an event into a webview's javascript side using something like

`@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    loadUrl("javascript:window.onDestroy();");
}`

which begs the question why Cordova doesnt if it's so simple? Can there be an issue where the WebView may miss the event for some reason?

And if so, why is such an event not fired into the plugins themselves?

Comment: Have look at this article: https://www.polyglotprogramminginc.com/interacting-with-the-android-lifecycle-in-a-cordova-plugin/

Comment: @David Thanks for the link but it was one of the first on google. I'm concerned that there might be an underlying issue since this typically necessary set of events yet was let out of the core framework

Comment: I don't think it's really an issue because usually you do not need the lifecycle events of the java activity when creating a webapp inside the webview. If a plugin creates another activity besides MainActivity you as the plugin developer have full control over the lifecycle anyway. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @David your right when it comes the webapp specific perspective, but Cordova is not intended for webapp development alone. Many major apps use hybrid architectures that rely minimally on web services. Is that not one of the major hooks for their viability? leveraging HTML5 and other advances in browser related technologies to cross beyond the web and into general purpose programming? These are cornerstone events for any form of framework - knowing when things are fully initialized, and knowing when things are shutting down. Especially when it comes to a native pluggin.

Comment: @David The rant is over Cordova, not you. Thank you for the input

Comment: I think I'm going to put a hefty bounty on this one. Specifically I need to know what issues may come up if I create a workaround. I'm heavily assuming that Cordova would have included such events if possible, especially when considering the interest that I've seen while searching the issue.

Comment: No worries! It's just that I never ran into any problems regarding this during the development of my plugins. The `initialize()` method was alway enough to know when my plugin is ready and as described in the article you can use `onDestroy()` but I'm not sure it's possible to send a callbackResult back to the webview at this time (or to still catch it in js) as the activity (hosting the webview) is as good as shut down.

Answer (score 0):

The following plugin attempts to patch that requirement:
https://github.com/agamemnus/cordova-plugin-ondestroy

However, please note that the `onStop` callback should be used instead to perform resources cleanup before leaving the app.